# Custom loading view not showing on calling show() and dismiss() method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I am trying to implement a custom loading view when the user clicks on upload to show loading. When calling show() it's working perfectly but on calling dismiss(). It shows nothing

I have done all the googling and search for a similar problem on StackOverflow

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
      switch (v.getId()){
          case R.id.socialMediaShareImage:
              getImageFromStorage();
              break;
          case R.id.socialMediaShareButton:
              catLoadingView.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
              //loadingDialog = LoadingDialog.Companion.get(SocialMediaActivity.this).show();
              uploadImageToServer();
              catLoadingView.dismiss();
              break;
              default:
                  Log.i("ERROR INSWITCH","id mismatch");
      }

   }

When clicking on share button the loading  view appear and dismiss after executing the uploadImageToServer() method.
```

Comment: I guess `uploadImageToServer()` method works on a new thread and gets callback on it and method `dismiss()` is called on the same thread. All the methods related to view components should be called on `Main thread`. So try to get back to main thread after your async process and then call `dismiss()`

Comment: uploadImageToServer() method is in UI thread . I haven't created a new thread@David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, method `uploadImageToServer()` performs some network-related action. If it does, you should do it on non-UI thread. Besides, in your code `catLoadingView.dismiss();` will not wait until your async process is done and will hide loading view immediately. You should use some callback method to fix your upload process finish and then dismiss your view.

It will look like this:

Your callback interface:

```
interface MyCallback {
    void onUploaded();
}
```

your upload method:

```
void upload(MyCallback callback) {
  // some async process on non-UI thread
  callback.onUploaded();
}
```

Finally, call your method:

```
case R.id.socialMediaShareButton:
          catLoadingView.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
          //loadingDialog = LoadingDialog.Companion.get(SocialMediaActivity.this).show();
          uploadImageToServer(new MyCallback() {
              runOnUiThread {
                 catLoadingView.dismiss();
              }
          });
          break;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for explaining in a simple way. The solution worked.